# Booktabs: midrules won't take the width I point out

Tags: tables, booktabs

[image]How does booktabs decide which midrules to give bigger width? Fixing them with `\midrule[0.5em]` does not work for all.

I am creating an unusual table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}       % enable includegraphics
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \caption{Summary Table - Difference-in-Differences Estimator\label{tab1}}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         \\
        &         All         &   Less\_corr         &   More\_corr         &    Less\_dem         &    More\_dem         \\
        \midrule



    25km&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police&      0.0201\sym{*}         &     -0.0163         &      0.0550\sym{**}         &      0.0988\sym{***}         &     -0.0128         \\
    \addlinespace
    Permit&      0.0129         &     -0.0255\sym{**}         &      0.0555\sym{**}         &       0.107\sym{***}         &     -0.0154         \\
     \midrule


    75km&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
     Police&     0.00786         &     -0.0134         &      0.0323\sym{*}         &      0.0687\sym{***}         &     -0.0190\sym{*}         \\
      \addlinespace
     Permit&     0.00100         &     -0.0150\sym{*}         &      0.0224         &      0.0528\sym{***}         &     -0.0147         \\
     \midrule


     Rounds 2-4&&&&&\\
     \addlinespace
     Police&      0.0396\sym{**}         &     0.00487         &      0.0783\sym{***}         &      0.0814\sym{***}         &      0.0112         \\
      \addlinespace
     Permit&      0.0471\sym{***}         &    0.000628         &      0.0979\sym{***}         &       0.109\sym{***}         &      0.0140         \\
     \midrule


    Rounds 3-5&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police&      0.0146         &    -0.00887         &      0.0418\sym{*}         &      0.0815\sym{***}         &    -0.00929         \\
    \addlinespace
    Permit&     0.00899         &     -0.0104         &      0.0382         &      0.0780\sym{***}         &    -0.00763         \\
    \midrule


    Incl. non-ODA&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police&      0.0145\sym{*}         &    -0.00938         &      0.0430\sym{**}         &      0.0573\sym{***}         &    -0.00892         \\
    \addlinespace
    Permit&     0.00495         &    -0.00759         &      0.0211         &      0.0517\sym{***}         &     -0.0136         \\
    \midrule


    Ordinal Variables&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police ordinal&      0.0196         &     -0.0303\sym{*}  &      0.0709\sym{*}   &       0.129\sym{***}  &     -0.0333\\       
    \addlinespace
    Permit ordinal&      0.0126        &     -0.0291\sym{*}     &      0.0592         &       0.137\sym{***}    &     -0.0292\\
    \midrule


    Alternative Outcomes&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    School&    -0.00494         &    -0.00629         &      0.0151       &      0.0607\sym{***}  &     -0.0246\sym{**}\\
    \addlinespace

    Water&     -0.0108         &     -0.0282\sym{**}  &      0.0162           &      0.0554\sym{***}       &     -0.0377\sym{***}\\



    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Robust standard errors (clustered by survey clusters) in parentheses}\\
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.05 ** p<0.01 *** p<0.001}\\
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize All estimations include baseline individual controls, year fixed effects and region fixed effects}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}





\end{document}
```

The entries obviously do not actually repete themselves. Somehow, randomly some of the midrules have bigger width. I tried to fix the width using `\midrule[0.5em]`, but then some of the lines randomly do not obey. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apart from the obvious errors in the fact that the numbers are not typeset in math mode, so the minus signs are all wrong, the rules are as expected. PDF previewers may make them look uneven, but it's just a question related to screen resolution.

Comment: Hope this is better

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMNMT.png)  try zooming in or out in your pdf viewer and you may see slight artifacts as the rules are snapped to pixel boundaries, but basically they are all the same width.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `siunitx` and `threeparttable` to improve the look of the table, and some `\multicolumn`s for the group headers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside, UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=25mm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} % enable includegraphics
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx, caption, threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{\,#1}\else\(^{\,#1}\)\fi}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.5, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-post=$^{\,***}$, table-align-text-post=false, group-digits=false}
    \caption{Summary Table - Difference-in-Differences Estimator\label{tab1}}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{S}*{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}S@{}}
        \toprule
        & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} \\
        & {All} & {Less\_corr} & {More\_corr} & {Less\_dem} & {More\_dem} \\
        \midrule
    25km&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police& 0.0201\sym{*} & -0.0163 & 0.0550\sym{**} & 0.0988\sym{***} & -0.0128 \\
    \addlinespace
    Permit& 0.0129 & -0.0255\sym{**} & 0.0555\sym{**} & 0.107\sym{***} & -0.0154 \\
     \midrule
    75km&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
     Police& 0.00786 & -0.0134 & 0.0323\sym{*} & 0.0687\sym{***} & -0.0190\sym{*} \\
      \addlinespace
     Permit& 0.00100 & -0.0150\sym{*} & 0.0224 & 0.0528\sym{***} & -0.0147 \\
     \midrule
     Rounds 2-4&&&&&\\
     \addlinespace
     Police& 0.0396\sym{**} & 0.00487 & 0.0783\sym{***} & 0.0814\sym{***} & 0.0112 \\
      \addlinespace
     Permit& 0.0471\sym{***} & 0.000628 & 0.0979\sym{***} & 0.109\sym{***} & 0.0140 \\
     \midrule
    Rounds 3-5&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police& 0.0146 & -0.00887 & 0.0418\sym{*} & 0.0815\sym{***} & -0.00929 \\
    \addlinespace
    Permit& 0.00899 & -0.0104 & 0.0382 & 0.0780\sym{***} & -0.00763 \\
    \midrule
    Incl. non-ODA&&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
    Police& 0.0145\sym{*} & -0.00938 & 0.0430\sym{**} & 0.0573\sym{***} & -0.00892 \\
    \addlinespace
    Permit& 0.00495 & -0.00759 & 0.0211 & 0.0517\sym{***} & -0.0136 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Ordinal Variables} \\
    \addlinespace
    Police ordinal& 0.0196 & -0.0303\sym{*} & 0.0709\sym{*} & 0.129\sym{***} & -0.0333\\
    \addlinespace
    Permit ordinal& 0.0126 & -0.0291\sym{*} & 0.0592 & 0.137\sym{***} & -0.0292\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Alternative Outcomes} \\
    \addlinespace
    School& -0.00494 & -0.00629 & 0.0151 & 0.0607\sym{***} & -0.0246\sym{**}\\
    \addlinespace
    Water& -0.0108 & -0.0282\sym{**} & 0.0162 & 0.0554\sym{***} & -0.0377\sym{***}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]\footnotesize\smallskip
  \item[Robust standard errors (clustered by survey clusters) in parentheses]
\item[* p<0.05\enspace ** p<0.01\enspace *** p<0.001]
\item[All estimations include baseline individual controls, year fixed effects and region fixed effects]
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]